# Converting the JS of a page to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on my new website and learning React at the same time. So I am trying to convert the JS functionality of my old website which was made with no JS librabries or frameworks to React.

The old JS:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const navigationElementHeight = document.querySelector("#navigation-bar")
        .offsetHeight;
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links a");
    const pageContent = document.querySelector(".content");

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        if (window.innerWidth > 576) {
            nav.classList.remove("nav-active");
            burger.classList.remove("toggle");
            pageContent.style.animation = "";
            navLinks.forEach(link => {
                if (link.style.animation) {
                    link.style.animation = "";
                }
            });
        }
    });

    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
        nav.style.top = `${navigationElementHeight}px`;

        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = "";
                if (!Object.is(pageContent, null)) {
                    pageContent.style.animation =
                        "movePageContentLeft 0.5s ease forwards";
                }
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFadeIn 0.3s ease forwards ${index / 7 +
                    0.5}s`;
                if (!Object.is(pageContent, null)) {
                    pageContent.style.animation =
                        "movePageContentRight 0.5s ease forwards";
                }
            }
        });

        burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
    });
};

navSlide();
```

The react component that I made:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import styles from "./styling/navbar.module.less"

const Navbar = ( props ) => {

  let toggleNavBar = () => {
    
    //Toggle the navbar

  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', windowResized)
    
  return (
    <nav id={"navigation-bar"}>
      <div className={styles.navLinks}>
        {props.pages.map(page => (
          <Link key={page.name} className={`${styles.navLink} ${styles.navElement} ${styles.navLinkHoverEffect}`} to={page.link}>
              {page.name}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
      //Burger Button
      <div className={styles.burger} onClick={toggleNavBar}>
        <div className={styles.line1}></div>
        <div className={styles.line2}></div>
        <div className={styles.line3}></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

So the burger button should apply a class to the `div` inside the `nav` element when pressed. What is the best way to do that? Also what do you think about the component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a state prop

```
const [isClicked, toggleIsClicked] = useState(false);
```

a toggle function

```
const toggleNavBar = () => {
  toggleIsClicked((isClicked)=> !isClicked); 
}
```

and conditionally render the div's class

```
 <div className={isClicked ? styles.navLinks : null}>
```

Edit:
For the animation not sure of the exact implementation off the top of my head but:

create a state prop that houses the delay time **and** remove animation-delay from your css selector.

```
const [delay, setDelay] = useEffect(0);
```

pass the state prop to the style attribute

```
<div className="your-animation-class" style={{animationDelay: `${delay}s`}}>
```

and in your button also call

```
setDelay((delay) => delay + .05)
```

The above implements a starting delay of 0 but you could set that to anything.

Comment: Can you also help with how should I go about applying custom styling to each element for the animation? Each Link element should have a custom style with an animation that changes.

Comment: are the animations changed by a user action and if so what action?

Comment: It's just one animation that changes its delay. Here is how it was done before `navLinkFadeIn 0.3s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s;` So for each element it would start running after longer and longer.

Comment: The action that should trigger the animations is the same burger button.

Comment: I think I can use the index off of the map function I used in the React component. In the original script it was the index of the certain link the animation was for, since all the links were in an object. Thank for you help!